# Jenkins - Execute system Groovy script plugin (Build step)

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hi i'm trying to execute a groovy script inside the system Groovy script, i'm trying to import "groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder", unfortunately i'm getting an error - `unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder`
Is there any way to use this package ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is Grape support for system groovy Jenkins scripts you might try to use [dependency management with Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html).
In your case it might be:

`@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
import org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder`

Dependencies are getting from Maven so Master need to have Maven binary on it's configuration.